# How to append a DOM element to target upon ajax completion with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So basically I have some content inside an element and an empty element after that, I press a button, ajax loads content from other page into the empty element, then the old element slides up, gets removed then the element with new content gets old element's ID and spawns a new empty element under itself.

Basic train-type content switching. My code is this:

```
    $("#products").click(function () {
        $("#next").load("products.php section");
        $("#content").slideUp("slow", function () { $(this).remove(); });
        $("#next").attr("id", "content");
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
            $("#content").after("<div id=\"next\"></div>");
        });
    });
```

Seems so friggin simple, yet it spawns the new "next" div BEFORE the slideup thing happens thus, the new renamed content div will be the last element in the page, whereas I need the next to be the last.

Before initiation my elements are like

```
<div id="content">
[some content inside]
</div>
<div id="next"></div>
```

Halfway through the operation they are like

```
<div id="content" style="height:0;">
[some content inside]
</div>
<div id="next">[some new content inside]</div>
```

And at the end of the operation they are like

```
<div id="next"></div>
<div id="content">
[some new content inside]
</div>
```

And everything is fine, except I need the end of operation order of elements be exactly the same as the beginning, so next should append. And it doesn't, even though I run it on `.ajaxComplete()`.

Code seems so simple, that I can't find any mistakes :/ There's no other code that would interfere. On `$(window).ready()` I run the `$("#content").after("<div id=\"next\"></div>");` line as well to generate the next div the first time around, but that's about it. Help?

Sorry I can't really provide reduced case example here, cuz `.load()` is local only.

Comment: Apologies cuz idk syntax, isnt there a `load(..).success(..)`? Next, do you need the ID selectors? Bc you can use `parent.children[0]` (or at least avoid ID and change) and you'll always have to animate the 1st.

Comment: I think I do get what you are trying but, I couldn't see which solutions I have in mind is good for you.  It'd be far easier if you pop your http://jsfiddle.net/ in here so we can see it.  Check it out and put your scripts like above into it and it'll run at the link - for easier for us to help you as we'd be able to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a potential timing issue with a race between the completion of the `slideUp()` which is when the old `#content` gets removed vs. the `.load()` which will become the new `#content`.  If the `.load()` finishes first, you will end up with two `#content` items which will confuse your ajaxComplete code as it won't necessarily operate on the right one.

This suggested code reworks the sequence of events to make it a lot more troublefree and insensitive to that timing.

First, we make the `slideUp()` operation completely stand-alone by removing it's attribute right away.  This makes sure we never have more than one `#content` element at once.

Second, we start the `.load()` on `#next` and immediately change it's attribute to `#content`. And finally, instead of triggering via `.ajaxComplete()`, we trigger using the completion function for the `.load()` and in that, we can use `$(this)` to make sure the new `#next` is added after the content we just loaded.  Done this way, there are no sensitivities to timing.  Here's the resulting code:

```
$("#products").click(function () {
    // slideup the old content, remove the #content attribute and 
    // then remove the content itself after it slides up
    $("#content").removeAttr("id")
        .slideUp("slow", function () { $(this).remove(); });

    $("#next").attr("id", "content").load("products.php section", function() {
        // add the #next after the new content to set things up for the next operation
        $(this).after('<div id="next"></div>');
    });
});
```

You will also notice that with jQuery chaining, there is exactly one sequence of operations on `#content` and one sequence of operations on `#next` making the code a lot clearer.

Comment: Yeah that is what I suspected, and your code is great and works like charm! Shows what a simple operation reorder can do...